# sink value is Void with publisher

Tags: swift, combine

Consider the below Observable Object.

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var age: Int
    @Published var name: String {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

The below code prints blank value or Void block. Any reason why? If we change Integer value age it should simply print that value.

```
let userJohnCancellable = userJohn.objectWillChange.sink { val in

    print("Changed Value \(val)")
    
}
userJohn.age = 21
userJohn.age = 39
```

We can try to print the values in the closure using `userJohn.age`. But why does val not return a Integer value in this case.

Also what would be the best way to handle `sink` changes for age and name, both, one is String other is Int.

Comment: You'll need to store the cancellable - see https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/combine-self-cancellable-memory-management. But maybe what you really need is `onReceive`, if you're using SwiftUI?

Comment: Also when you print the class, the properties won't get printed. Maybe you want a struct instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about ObservableObject. It is for use with SwiftUI. But your code is not SwiftUI code, so you don't need ObservableObject and you really can't use it in any meaningful way. If the goal is to be able to subscribe to the properties of User so as to be notified when one of them changes, then it suffices to make those properties Published:

```
class User {
    @Published var age: Int
    @Published var name: String
    init(age: Int, name: String) {
        self.age = age; self.name = name
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using it; I will assume we have a `user` property of a UIViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var user = User(age: 20, name: "Bill")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        user.$age.sink {print("age:", $0)}.store(in: &cancellables)
        user.$name.sink {print("name:", $0)}.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

If this view controller's `user` has its `age` or `name` changed, you'll see the `print` output in the console.

If the question is how to handle *both* changes in a *single* pipeline, they have different types, as you observe, so you'd need to define a union so that both types can come down the same pipeline:

```
class User {
    @Published var age: Int
    @Published var name: String
    enum Union {
        case age(Int)
        case name(String)
    }
    var unionPublisher: AnyPublisher<Union, Never>?
    init(age: Int, name: String) {
        self.age = age; self.name = name
        let ageToUnion = $age.map { Union.age($0) }
        let nameToUnion = $name.map { Union.name($0) }
        unionPublisher = ageToUnion.merge(with: nameToUnion).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And again, here's an example of using it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var user = User(age: 20, name: "Bill")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        user.unionPublisher?.sink { union in
            switch union {
            case .age(let age): print ("age", age)
            case .name(let name): print ("name", name)
            }
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Again, change the `user` property's `name` or `age` and you'll get an appropriate message in the console.

Comment: Regarding `let ageToUnion = $age.map { Union.age($0) }` , here Union.age(Int) has associated Type Int. Curios to know how does it allow mapping to Publisher.

Comment: I do not understand the question. In the phrase "how does it allow mapping to Publisher" I do not know what "it" is, or what "allow mapping to Publisher" means.

Answer (score 3):

When you look in the documentation for `ObservableObject` you will find that`objectWillChange` is `ObservableObjectPublisher`

```
/// A publisher that emits before the object has changed.
public var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher { get }
```

which in turn is defined as having an output of type `Void`:

```
final public class ObservableObjectPublisher : Publisher {

    /// The kind of values published by this publisher.
    public typealias Output = Void

    /// The kind of errors this publisher might publish.
    ///
    /// Use `Never` if this `Publisher` does not publish errors.
    public typealias Failure = Never

}
```

There is no need to send `objectWillChange` from `didSet` - each time any of the `@Published` values changes `objectWillChange` will emit a value.
If you want to get notified when a particular property marked as `@Published` changes and receive the new value you have to subscribe to that particular property:

```
let userJohn = User(name: "Johnny", age: 17)

let objectWillChangeCancellable = userJohn
    .objectWillChange
    .sink {
        print("object will change")
    }

let ageCancellable = userJohn
    .$age
    .sink { age in
        print("new value of age is \(age)")
    }

let nameCancellable = userJohn
    .$name
    .sink { name in
        print("new value of name is \(name)")
    }
```

This will get printed:

```
new value of age is 17
new value of name is Johnny
```

if you add:

```
userJohn.name = "John"
```

you will see the following printed:

```
object will change
new value of name is John
```

if you add:

```
userJohn.age = 21
```

you will see the following printed:

```
object will change
new value of age is 21
```